# r2_score is -18.709, Why?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm conducting multiple linear regression in Python, ML. To the best of my knowledge r2_score supposed to be in the range of -1 to 1. But, I obtained -18.709.

What is the problem to obtain this answer and how can I correct it? Its coding and result look as follows:

## calculate R

```py
from SK-learn.meterics import r2_score

score = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
print(score)
```

The output:

> -18.7097

## Its prediction result is as follows:

```py
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print(y_pred)
```

Result:

> [ 25000. 123000.  73000. 103000.]

Comment: We know from the first line that your code isn't real, so any attempt to guess would be futile.

Comment: @hobbs Rightly said.

Answer (score 0):

The coefficient of determination r-square is defined as

[image]

Nash–Sutcliffe model efficiency coefficient (Explanation below)

[image]

> There are cases where the computational definition of R2 can yield
> negative values, depending on the definition used. This can arise when
> the predictions that are being compared to the corresponding outcomes
> have not been derived from a model-fitting procedure using those data.
>
> Even if a model-fitting procedure has been used, R2 may still be
> negative, for example when linear regression is conducted without
> including an intercept, or when a non-linear function is used to fit
> the data. In cases where negative values arise, the mean of the data
> provides a better fit to the outcomes than do the fitted function
> values, according to this particular criterion. Since the most general
> definition of the coefficient of determination is also known as the
> Nash–Sutcliffe model efficiency coefficient, this last notation is
> preferred in many fields, because denoting a goodness-of-fit indicator
> that can vary from −∞ to 1 (i.e., it can yield negative values) with a
> squared letter is confusing.
>
> SOURCE: wikipedia

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is there any procedure to avoid this sort of output?